# How to write a jQuery function will data-id loop in order to show a certain element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, custom-data-attribute

I want to do a show/hide function, with clicking and identifying the data-id of element, the relative element with same id will be shown.

I knew that I can do:

```
$('a[data-id="s1"]').click(function() {
  $(div[data-value="s1"]).show();
});
$('a[data-id="s2"]').click(function() {
  $(div[data-value="s2"]).show();
});
$('a[data-id="s3"]').click(function() {
  $(div[data-value="s3"]).show();
});
```

... etc, but the code will be so long.

So I am just wondering if I can make those id like an array, and then loop them in jquery such that I can have a clean code.

I expect all the above can be done within a single function that I can identify s1/s2/s3... separately.

Thank you so much for reading my question and I hope to learn more from you guys. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- When an `<a>` is clicked:
- get the value of its `[data=id]`
- then go through `.each()` `<div>` to find the value of its `[data-value]`
- and compare each value and `.show()` `<div>` when matched.

This is the most encompassing and generic approach given the information in OP. A "**clean** one function" option is not feasible without more info like HTML, classes, etc.

```js
$('a').on('click', function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $('div').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).data('value');
    if (value === id) {
      $(this).show()
    }
  });
});
```

```css
hr~div {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<a href='#/' data-id='0'>0</a>
<a href='#/' data-id='1'>1</a>
<a href='#/' data-id='2'>2</a>
<hr>
<div data-value='0'>0</div>
<div data-value='1'>1</div>
<div data-value='2'>2</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reference the clicked element inside the callback of the click event by using `this`:
   `$('a').click(function() {
    console.log(this.dataset.id);
    })`

Comment: Try not to mix jquery with Vanilla JS if possible, instead of `this.dataset.id`, use jquery method `$(this).data('id')`

Answer (score 1):

you can set same class for `<a>` and try this:

```
<a class="sameClass" href="#" data-id="s1">a1</a>
```

```
$('.sameClass').click(function() {

    var dataId = $(this).data('id');

    $('div[data-value="' + dataId + '"]').show();

});
```